# (Soft Question) Why don't number theory books start with Peano axioms or derive the rule of product from first principles? Etc?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Every number theory book seems to start with divisibility, congruency, the division algorithm, etc., while completely ignoring the rigorous construction of the natural numbers. It seems like a wasted opportunity to explain to the reader what's actually happening.

I feel the same about combinatorics. Permutations, combinations, and the rule of product are derived heuristically rather than through rigorous arguments from set theory.

Is there a particular reason why number theory books take this approach rather than a rigorous from first principles approach?

Comment: I would imagine this is because such results are considered quite boring. I'd more likely expect rigorous constructions of $\Bbb N$ and its operations, etc., in a basic set theory or real analysis text

Comment: Starting with Peano is certainly the foundational approach, but it is not a good pedagogical approach - it introduces a lot of concepts that the reader is unfamiliar with and strips away a lot of basic knowledge the student already "knows." So, yes, we can prove commutativity of the binary operations in Peano, but this approach will be hard to grasp. Starting with Peano is better for a second or third pass through number theory, not a first pass.

Comment: @FShrike Interestingly, Tao is the only real analysis book (that I'm aware of) that starts this way. That fact actually prompted this question.

Comment: Before I learnt any real analysis at all I did a little googling about constructing $\Bbb N,\Bbb R$, etc. as a primer. I recommend that. But for learning about divisibility, as thomas says, this is a pedagogical nightmare. And by the point that the material is suitably advanced, well, the reader is already assumed to be "mathematically mature", right? So the text would assume the reader already (a) knows the rigorous constructions or (b) is aware that they exist and can be checked. I've never actually needed to return to how the basics work; once you believe in them, you are free to use them

Comment: I agree with the above, and also feel that in some way it doesn't seem necessary. For example, in real analysis, you care about the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ (for example, some notion of open/closed sets), and for that you need to consider something about how the $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}.$ But to define $\mathbb{Q}$ rigorously, you then need to define natural numbers very rigorously.

On the other hand, for number theory, you don't really need these sort of topological/set theoretic notions; the tools in number theory originate from other subjects.

Comment: Also, it depends too on the level of the number theory book. For example, if it's a number theory book for high schoolers (for example, at the olympiad level), then those rigorous constructions of the integers are not necessary. And if it's at the university level, then I agree with others above that probably some of this basic real analysis knowledge is known and it's not necessary to cover

Comment: Actually the [book](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-I-Herbert-Amann-ebook/dp/B00EJSOFQ4) by Amann/Escher starts with Peano axioms to construct $\mathbb N$. They even introduce groups rings and fields to construct $\mathbb R$. Moreover, they also prove that *"There is, up to isomorphism, a unique order complete extension field $\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. This extension is called the field of real numbers"* and that *"There is a smallest extension field $\mathbb{C}$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the field of complex numbers, in which the equation $z^2=-1$ is solvable. It is unique up to isomorphism"*.

Comment: As it turns out, I'm the only one fascinated by the Peano axioms!

Comment: if it wasn't for Analysis we wouldn't really care that much for rigourosuly developing number systems, the Integers are straightforward, the only reason it was rigioursly developed was because analysts needed it to develop the reals.

Comment: *Tao is the only real analysis book (that I'm aware of)* $\ldots$ --- See [**Fundamentals of Abstract Analysis**](https://archive.org/details/fundamentalsofab0000unse) by Gleason (1966). He doesn't even get to the Peano axioms until p. 89 (middle of Chapter 7). Among real analysis texts (includes complex analysis in last chapter), this is the most thorough for going from propositional & predicate logic to set theory to functions & relations to inductive definitions & natural numbers (and proofs of arithmetic operations) to ordered sets/fields to rational numbers & real numbers that I know of.

Comment: "As it turns out, I'm the only one fascinated by the Peano axioms!" Not so. For starters, take a look at this bibliography. https://diagonalargument.com/mathnotes/nonstandard-models-of-arithmetic-the-series/#bibliography.

Comment: Number theorists are primarily interested in what's true about $\mathbb{N}$ (and not just $\mathbb{N}$, but related structures, like algebraic number fields). Provability from PA is of interest primarily to logicians. (Of course, I'm oversimplifying.)

Comment: Why do you feel putting Peano axioms in a number theory book would help people understand number theory better or reveal "what's actually happening"?  People used integers (at least positive ones) for thousands of years without feeling that anything was missing and there was no foundational crisis involving just integers. It is *analysis* that has many subtle issues where many intuitive theorems are wrong (e.g., people once thought differentiable functions are continuous except at isolated points). Foundational issues (like failure of unique factorization) occur in *algebraic* number theory.

Comment: @KCd Do you mean to say that people thought that _continuous_ functions are _differentiable_ except at isolated points? I'm having trouble thinking of a way of interpreting the statement "differentiable functions are continuous except at isolated points" that makes it false.

Comment: @TannerSwett yes, that's what I meant to write.  

Comment: Should a baker's cookbook begin with the chemical reactions? Sure, it's interesting for someone wanting to learn everything from the ground up, but it is really pertinent if all you want to do is learn how to bake a cake?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My PhD is about models of PA (Peano Arithmetic), so I yield to none when it comes to fascination with this topic. Still, I wouldn't say that formal derivations in PA are "what's actually happening".

I would say this is an aspect of what you might call the library shelving problem. Mathematics is conventionally divided into various subfields, but the boundaries are not sharp, and shift over time.

Number theory has a loooong history, going back to the ancient Greeks, at least. Two topics you mention (divisibility, the division algorithm) are found in Euclid. For almost all of that history, $\mathbb{N}$ was regarded unproblematically. That is, while open questions have always been part of this history, foundational issues weren't. The real numbers grabbed all the exciting foundational attention. (My terminology, of course, is blatantly anachronistic.)

In the eighteenth and nineteenth century, the field of number theory expanded to include algebraic and analytic number theory. Peano's axioms and the subsequent history of PA start at the beginning of the twentieth century. The people pursuing these questions were primarily logicians. Overlapping interests existed, of course. Dedekind made major contributions to number theory, but also wrote "Was Sind und Sollen die Zahlen?" Skolem wrote papers on Diophantine equations as well as his celebrated work in logic.

Someone writing a number theory textbook probably is thinking something like, "OK, I've got to cover the basic stuff in the first few chapters. Maybe I'll end the book on a high note with [algebraic number fields / special cases of Fermat's theorem / the prime number theorem ....]" or whatever their special interest is. They are probably *not* looking forward to writing up a bunch of formal derivations in PA.

---

Addendum: A friend of mine recently had his number theory [textbook](https://www.routledge.com/Introduction-to-Number-Theory/Hunacek/p/book/9781032017204?_ga=1659364734.1689029034&_gl=1*2zj3bg*_ga*MTY1OTM2NDczNC4xNjg5MDI5MDM0*_ga_0HYE8YG0M6*MTY4OTAyOTAzNS4xLjAuMTY4OTAyOTAzNS4wLjAuMA..) published. He begins Chapter 1 with a discussion of induction, and gives the Peano axioms in an appendix.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I feel like the same is true for real analysis. I own perhaps 10 analysis books, and every single ones seems to use Principles of Mathematical Analysis as a guide for what to cover and when. Tao seems to be the only one who is brave enough to do his own thing!

Comment: I think the two cases are significantly different. Foundational issues with the real numbers emerged already with the Ancient Greeks (expressed differently of course). And you need to discuss them in some manner to prove basic results like the IVT. Note that most calculus books don’t go into this. That’s more like the situation with books on elementary number theory.